# Making a table with fixed columns versus key-valued pairs of metadata?

Tags: database, database-design

I was asked to create a table to store paid-hours data from multiple attendance systems from multiple geographies from multiple sub-companies. This table would be used for high level reporting so basically it is skipping the steps of creating tables for each system (which might exist) and moving directly to what the final product would be.

The request was to have a dimension for each type of hours or pay like this:

```
date       | employee_id   | type          | hours  | amount
2016-04-22      abc123      regular           80       3500
2016-04-22      abc123      overtime          6        200
2016-04-22      abc123      adjustment        1        13
2016-04-22      abc123      paid time off     24       100
2016-04-22      abc123      commission                 600
2016-04-22      abc123      gross total                4413
```

There are multiple rows per employee but the though process is that this will allow us to capture new dimensions if they are added.

The data is coming from several sources and I was told not to worry about the ETL, but just design the ultimate table and make it work for any system. We would provide this format to other people for them to fill in.

I have only seen the raw data from one system and it like this:

```
date | employee_id | gross_total_amount | regular_hours | regular_amount | OT_hours  | OT_amount | classification | amount | hours
```

It is pretty messy. Multiple rows for employees and values like gross_total repeat each row. There is a classification column which has items like PTO (paid time off), adjustments, empty values, commission, etc. Because of repeating values, it is impossible to just simply sum the data up to make it equal the gross_total_amount.

Anyways, I kind of would prefer to do a column based approach where each row describes the employees paid hours for a cut off. One problem is that I won't know all of the possible types of hours which are possible so I can't necessarily make a table like:

```
date | employee_id | gross_total_amount | commission_amount | regular_hours | regular_amount | overtime_hours | overtime_amount | paid_time_off_hours | paid_time_off_amount | holiday_hours | holiday_amount
```

I am more used to data formatted that way though. The concern is that you might not capture all of the necessary columns or if something new is added. (For example, I know there is maternity leave, paternity leave, bereavement leave, in other geographies there are labor laws about working at night, etc)

Any advice? Is the table which was suggested to me from my superior a viable solution?

Answer (score 2):

Let me recapitulate what I understand to be the basic task.

You get data from different sources, having different structures. Your task is to consolidate them in a single database to be able to answer questions about all these data. I understand the hint about "not to worry about the ETL, but just design the ultimate table" in that way that your consolidated database doesn't need to contain all detail information that might be present in the original data, but just enough information to fulfill the specific requirements to the consolidated database.

This sounds sensible as long as your superior is certain enough about these requirements. In that case, you will reduce the information coming from each source to the consolidated structure.

In any way, you'll have to capture the domain semantics of the data coming in from each source. Lacking access to your domain semantics, I can't clarify the mess of repeating values etc. for you. E.g., if there are detail records and gross total records, as in your example, it would be wrong to add the hours of all records, as this would always yield twice the hours actually worked. So someone will have to worry about ETL, namely interpreting each set of records, probably consisting of all entries for an employee and one working day, find out what they mean, and transform them to the consolidated structure.

I understand another part of the question to be about the usage of metadata. You can have different columns for notions like holiday leave and maternity leave, or you have a metadata table containing these notions as a key-value pair, and refer to the key from your main table. The metadata way is sometimes praised as being more flexible, as you can introduce a new type (like paternity leave) without redesigning your database. However, you will need to redesign the software filling and probably also querying your tables to make use of the new type. So you'll have to develop and deploy a new software release anyway, and adding a few columns to a table will just be part of that development effort.

There is one major difference between a broad table containing all notions as attributes and the metadata approach. If you want to make sure that, for a time period, either all or none of the values are present, that's easy with the broad table: Just make all attributes `not null´, and you're done. Ensuring this for the metadata solution would mean some rather complicated constraint that may or may not be available depending on the database system you use.

If that's not a main requirement, I would go a pragmatic way and use different columns if I expect only a handful of those types, and a separate key-value table otherwise.

All these considerations relied on your superior's assertion (as I understand it) that your consolidated table will only need to fulfill the requirements known today, so you are free to throw original detail information away if it's not needed due to these requirements. I'm wary of that kind of assertion. Let's assume some of your information sources deliver additional information. Then it's quite probable that someday someone asks for a report also containing this information, where present. This won't be possible if your data structure only contains what's needed today.

There are two ways to handle this, i.e. to provide for future needs. You can, after knowing the data coming from each additional source, extend your consolidated database to cover all data structures coming from there. This requires some effort, as different sources might express the same concept using different data, and you would have to consolidate those to make the data comparable. Also, there is some probability that not all of your effort will be worth the trouble, as not all of the detail information you get will actually be needed for your consolidated database. Another more elegant way would therefore be to keep the original data that you import for each source, and only in case of a concrete new requirement, extend your database and reimport the data from the sources to cover the additional details. Prices of storage being low as they are, this might yield an optimal cost-benefit ratio.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all of the details. I would certainly be storing a table with the raw data (cleaned up version) for each system. My superior only cares about the ultimate table. My approach was to look at a sample of each report first and talk to some experts in the finance department (ultimately the raw data is used for payroll, so there must be someone with the full understanding) to figure out the different dimensions and definitions and calculations. So your suggestion is to add columns, then if we need to add something later we can?

Comment: Also, is there a term for the row based structure that my superior suggested? It seems like it would be difficult to work with. I know a structure like that is not recommended in most cases. I tried to skim through my Data Warehouse book but couldn't find the example that I was looking for.

Comment: If you keep the original data anyway, I'd only include in the consolidated database what's currently needed. This is an application of the yagni (you ain't gonna need it) principle. Considering your second question, I'm not quite sure about which of the given structures was suggested by your superior. Basically, the laws of data modeling also apply for a data warehouse. What's the essence of where your solution and that of your superior are in conflict?

Comment: Me: a descriptive column per 'hour type' so one row describes the employee's pay cut-off (a two week period of time)

Superior: a single measure column called 'hours' and a dimension column called 'type' where all of the hour types are stored. This is a very narrow table and maybe I am just not used to it. Each row would repeat for the employee per payroll period to describe different hour types (regular, vacation, holiday, overtime, etc).

Comment: I extended the section about the metadata solution (your superior's), so I hope it gives some direction now. Either way won't break your neck.

Comment: BTW, the title of your question isn't very useful for someone who needs to solve a similar problem, which is not primarily about paid hours, but about modeling notions via fixed columns vs. key-value pairs of metadata. Would you care to edit the title to reflect that?

Answer (score 2):

TAM makes lots of good points, and I have only two additional suggestions.

First, I would generate some fake data in the table as described above, and see if it can generate the required reports.  Show your manager each of the reports based on the fake data, to check that they're OK.  (It appears that the reports are the ultimate objective, so work back from there.)

Second, I would suggest that you get sample data from as many of the input systems as you can.  This is to double check that what you're being asked to do is possible for all systems.  It's not so you can design the ETL, or gather new requirements, just testing it all out on paper (do the ETL in your head).  Use this to update the fake data, and generate fresh fake reports, and check the reports again.