# Approach to database to search price

Tags: database, database-design, spring-boot

I am about to build a backend for a platform to search for the best prices of vendors of vegetables. In short, customer is able to filter which vegetables or fruits he is interested in, and then the backend is able to response with JSON that will return the Name of the vendor and calculated price. Here is example of database that I am considering following `Vendors Table`:

```
+----+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID |   Name   | Potato | Tomato | Apple  |
+----+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Example1 |      5 |      5 |      6 |
|  2 | Example2 |        |      2 |      3 |
|  3 | Example3 |      8 |      9 |     10 |
+----+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Where values in Potato, Tomato and Apple are FK's to following tables (for example `Potato Table`:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Price |
+----+-------+
|  5 |    10 |
|  8 |    20 |
+----+-------+
```

So in short, when the value in first table of FK Potato is null, it means that vendor doesn't offer this product.

My question is: is this good approach of DB structure to then easily add new products that vendors may sell, and is it fast approach - will it need a lot of time when main table will have up to 10,000 records? If not, what changes would I need to implement?

I am considering SpringBoot as my backend. For algorithm search, I am considering querydsl.

Comment: no that is not a good design.

Comment: @MitchWheat, do you have any suggestions on how to change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a `Many-To-Many` relationship between `vendor` and `vegetable`, So you need another table to break down this relation, let us name it `vendor_vegetable` which may contains the `price` for each new relation between the main 2 tables.
[image]

Each record in `vendor_vegetable` expose new price, You may need to add more fields to this table like the date of putting the new price

**Edit:**

Your design not so good nor dynamic, Consider you need to add a new kind of fruit or vegetable (for ex. banana), Then you must alter `Vendors` table to add new column named `banana`, and then add a new table named `banana`.

Also what if you decide to change the name of `banana` ?

In `SQL` principles your problem is a known one: `Many-To-Many` relationship.
In this design you have only to add a new record to `vegetable` table, Then when you need to link the price of vendor with this new kink you have only to add new record to `vendor_vegetable` table.

Comment: Good design. To discuss deep, I have in table like your 'vendor_vegetable' fields of date range, price can be different in time. Example: in detail market planned 'price of day' action (my project: in next Thursday), or imagine international future transactions. Or current official offer is limited in time.

Comment: what about performance of this structure when you try to run query with multiple joins? is this better/more efficient than one big table? btw, if none of the other answers will show up within few days, I will grant you bounty

Comment: This is the standard structure for this issue, DBMS providers have optimize specific queries for best performance, You do not have to think about that. refer to this example from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables-film_actor.html from MySQL site.

Comment: So if you care about the speed of db that mean that you have a huge number of data, And in this case if you design your db in a none standard way, You will fall in a lot of troubles in the future. @kaviddiss

Answer (score 0):

You can think about this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_delete`.`vendors` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique ID of the Vendor',
  `name` VARCHAR(40) NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Vendor\n',
  `area` VARCHAR(200) NULL COMMENT 'Area where the vendor is located',
  `is_active` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Whether or not the vendor is active.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `test_delete`.`items` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique ID of the item',
  `item_name` VARCHAR(40) NULL COMMENT 'Name of the item',
  `item_price` DOUBLE NULL COMMENT 'The price of the item',
  `is_active` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Whether the item is discontinued or not.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `test_delete`.`vendor_item_availability` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique ID of the Item Vendor Availability matrix.',
  `vendor_id` INT NULL COMMENT 'FK Vendor ID from Vendors table.',
  `item_id` INT NULL COMMENT 'FK Item ID from Items table',
  `availability_count` INT NULL COMMENT 'Count of items available',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_vendor_id_idx` (`item_id` ASC, `vendor_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_item_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`)
    REFERENCES `test_delete`.`items` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vendor_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`)
    REFERENCES `test_delete`.`vendors` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Made a little modification to serve a wider purpose

Answer (score 0):

If the requirements you describe are complete, you don't need the second table. Have a row for each vendor in the first table. (At least that's how I interpret the first table, `ID` and `Name` being id and name of the vendor.) Then, in each fruit column, enter the price of the vendor for this product directly, and you're done. When the price is `null`, this means the vendor doesn't sell the product.

An alternative would be to have a separate table for the types of fruit and an m:n relationship between vendor and fruit. This is discussed in [Making a table with fixed columns versus key-valued pairs of metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811009/making-a-table-with-fixed-columns-versus-key-valued-pairs-of-metadata/36813692#36813692).